How to access unknown fields in python protobuf version 5.38.3 with upb backend
I'm using Python protobuf package version 5.38.3 for deserializing some packets and I need to check if the messages I deserialize are conformant or not to a specific protobuf message structure. For some checks I want to obtain the list of unknown fields.
This post points to an API UnknownFields() supported by messages, but when I call it in a deserialized message it raises NotImplementedError.
How can I get access to the list of unknown fields from a deserialized message in protobuf 5.28.3?


How can I get access to the list of unknown fields

Here, let me google that for you.
https://protobuf.dev/news/2023-08-15

Python Breaking Change
In v25 message.UnknownFields() will be deprecated in pure Python and C++ extensions. It will be removed in v26. Use the new UnknownFieldSet(message) support in unknown_fields.py as a replacement.

You will want to update your code to use the new
public API.

I did google it, just that result did not come up. I've been using protocol buffers for a while in C++, Kotlin, Java & C#, so far I've just done a few little/simple things in Python ;). Thanks!
